# Some problems regarding Fourier transform.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{C}$ be an integrable function. Let for some $m,n(>m)\geq 0,$ $f$ satisfies
$$\int_m^n e^{itz}f(t)dt\equiv 0, ~ \text{for all } z\in \mathbb{H}^+,$$
where $\mathbb{H}^+ =\{z|Im(z)>0\} .$

1.Is it true that $f\equiv0$ on $[m,n]$?

2. Is the above remains true if $n=\infty$?

Edit after the answer:

3. Is (1),(2) remain true if we assume that $f$ is bounded instead of integrable?

($\equiv$ stands for 'equal almost everywhere'.)

Comment: The answer is no if we don't have stronger constraints on $f$.  For a simple example, $f$ could be zero everywhere except on the integers, where it is $1$. ... Or do you intend $\equiv$ to mean equality almost everywhere, rather than identicality?

Comment: Yes indeed I meant almost everywhere.

Comment: Notation is not universal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_v(t) = e^{-vt} f(t)$.  Suppose that $f_v$ is integrable for some $v > 0$, which is the case if $f$ is measurable and bounded.

Your hypothesis tells us that the Fourier transform of $f_v \chi_{[m,n]}$ is zero, implying that $f_v \chi_{[m,n]} = 0$, that is, $f(z) = 0$ a.e. on $[m,n]$.  It works even if $n = \infty$.

Comment: Thank you sir for your reply. I have 2 questions regarding this. 1st one I added in the question. 2nd one is: your answer implying that it is enough to take $\mathbb{H}^+=\{z|0<Im(z)<1\}$. Isn't it?

Comment: It is enough to consider $\mathbb H^+ = \{z | \text{Im}(z) = v\}$ for some $v > 0$.

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much for further generalizing the result.